How can I apply for a J1 visa while my B1/B2 visa application is still under administrative processing?
I applied for a B1 visa to visit the US a few months back from India. That application is currently under process and my appointment is scheduled for March 2025. However, I recently got a fellowship to study in the USA, for which I need a J1 visa. To apply for the J1, do I need to cancel my existing B1 visa appointment and reapply? Or are there other ways in which this can be done? When I log into my portal, I can't see an option to change my visa, only to cancel the appointment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Visa appointments for J visas are handled separately from those for B visas and you will have to make a new appointment for a new visa type.
However, the good news for you is that J visa appointments can usually be made much more readily than B visa appointments. You can check the estimates for your location on the State Deparment's website, but for example, as of this writing, in Mumbai, J visas have a 15 day wait time—much better than the 499 days for a B visa. You probably wouldn't want to convert your old appointment even if it were allowed!

Thank you! I had to cancel by B1/B2 appointment and reapply for the J1 Visa. And as you said, the appointment wait time is much lesser :)
